# How to send Android photo to Azure Virtual machine

Tags: android, azure, azure-devops, virtual-machine, photo

I am trying to figure out the best way to send a photo from my new android app to my Azure VM. Most of the development for the app is done, but I am struggling with the best method to send the photo (Selected by user on android device) to Azure and have it land in a folder on a virtual machine I have setup. I have tried a few things including FTP on the VM, but it seems API is the standard/is more secure. I have tried to create a function in Azure to handle this for me, and i have tried to create an REST API in Visual Studio (published to azure) to handle the task for me, and with neither solution can i get the file to land on the virtual machine. I kind of feel like my limited Azure knowledge is what is hurting me, but i also would like help with deciding the best method for my workflow.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create an API that puts the image in a specific container in an [Azure Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/) account.

You can then have the VM monitor that container, pick up the image and process it.

***Question:***
Does it really have to be a VM? Because for instance [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/) can be triggered by files being added to a specific Storage container.

**EDIT:**
How are you accessing the storage account inside the VM? Judging by your question, you probably don't have the correct permissions for your storage account. If you're using a Shared Access Signature, you should have one that gives you the right permissions (see image):

[image: Creating a Shared Access Signature]

Comment: Thanks! I tried something similar to this, and inside my VM i could access/view the file, but i could not copy/move/delete it. Seemed i only had read privs. Is there another configuration I need to get read/write? 

The image needs to be edited by a human with limited technical skills, and so the VM is an environment where i can stash the photo in a folder for them, and they simply can login, retrieve the photo, and log out. Im open to other suggestions though!

Comment: @S.Galloway Have a look at my edit for additional information.